# Access server side property file in javascript

Tags: javascript, spring, file, jakarta-ee

I wrote all message in server side property file. in alert box i have to show some message for validation.

Path of property file is "WebContent-WEB-INF-APT Properties-frequency.properties".

so How can i access server side properties file in ".js" file or javascript.

Any suggetion will be helpful, Thanks in advance...!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't, they are entirely separate layers.

*Server Side Layer*
Generates the files, including `HTML` output.

Server side can *also* provide `CSS` and `Javascript` though they are not run.

**Client Side**
By the time it gets to the browser, the source of the source of the `HTML` no longer matters.   This is straight HTML, completely devoid of its source.

If you need something to be available to the server, it has either

- Be generated ON the server and given to the client
- Be generated on the client and passed UP to the client via Aja

Comment: Thanks for Reply Jeremy, So is there any way to pass message from property file to client via Ajax?? also I tried using ajax but i am not able to access...

Comment: I don't use `Java` myself, but a quick Google for `communicate java ajax` brought me to [this link](http://javapapers.com/ajax/getting-started-with-ajax-using-java/) which seemed fairly complete.